# Where can I find which packages are available as tds.zip?

Tags: packages, ctan, tds

When I need to install a package manually I much prefer to use the ready-zipped TEX Directory Structure-compliant version rather than install it manually with `.dtx` or `.ins` files. Normally when I want to do this, I just search for `package.tds.zip` which normally gets it. But I'd really just like a list or a searchable database of those packages that are available as a tds.zip version.

CTAN doesn't seem to make this information available, as you might expect it would. (weirdly, CTAN will link to *a* zip file, but not the tds.zip file...)

I found [this list on CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/install/macros/latex/contrib), but it doesn't seem comprehensive.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

AFAIK the TDS ZIP files need to be provided by the package authors and are only then available in the http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/install/macros/latex/contrib directory. It seems that the author of that particular package didn't uploaded a TDS ZIP file.

I also agree that the TDS ZIP files are hard to find. I wondered for a while if the ones I uploaded (together with a normal ZIP file) are really used. It would be nice if the web interface of CTAN (`http://www.ctan.org/pkg/<PACKAGE>`) would also link to these files.
However, the TDS ZIP file of a package is linked by the TeX catalogue entry at `http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/<PACKAGE>.html` under *Distributions* and in the package page on `http://ctanhg.scharrer-online.de/pkg/<PACKAGE>` under *On CTAN* (usually the last in the list).

---

If you are looking for a list of all available TDS ZIP files instead:

There is a text file which lists all files under http://mirrors.ctan.org/FILES.byname. It shows that almost all TDS ZIP files are under `/install/...` where `...` represents their normal location on CTAN, i.e. `/install/macros/latex/contrib` for contributed LaTeX packages. An exception are the one which are placed in the `graphics` folder (e.g. PGF/TikZ supporting packages like `tikz-timing`). The only one there is my `tikz-timing` package located at `/install/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-timing.tds.zip`.
The fonts, support and info related TDS ZIP files are in the appropriate subdirectories below `/install`.

A full list can be produces by downloading the above mentioned `FILES.byname` file and use e.g. `grep '\.tds\.zip' FILES.byname` on it. The result is shown below. If it isn't listed there, it is not on CTAN. However, it is of course possible that the author or someone else uploaded it only on its private website or other place.

```
install/biblio/bibtex/contrib/gost.tds.zip
install/fonts/ae.tds.zip
install/fonts/auto1.tds.zip
install/fonts/bickham.tds.zip
install/fonts/ccicons.tds.zip
install/fonts/cm/cmtiup.tds.zip
install/fonts/cmll.tds.zip
install/fonts/countriesofeurope.tds.zip
install/fonts/doublestroke.tds.zip
install/fonts/fdsymbol.tds.zip
install/fonts/figbas.tds.zip
install/fonts/frcursive.tds.zip
install/fonts/gillcm.tds.zip
install/fonts/jamtimes.tds.zip
install/fonts/kpfonts.tds.zip
install/fonts/mathgifg.tds.zip
install/fonts/mdputu.tds.zip
install/fonts/mdsymbol.tds.zip
install/fonts/newtx.tds.zip
install/fonts/pcarl.tds.zip
install/fonts/psfonts/adobe/futurans.tds.zip
install/fonts/psfonts/adobe/nbaskerv.tds.zip
install/fonts/psfonts/emigre/dogma.tds.zip
install/fonts/psfonts/fontfabrik/thsmc.tds.zip
install/fonts/semaphor.tds.zip
install/fonts/softmakerfreefont/alteschwabacher.tds.zip
install/fonts/softmakerfreefont/artistic.tds.zip
install/fonts/softmakerfreefont/baskervillenova.tds.zip
install/fonts/softmakerfreefont/bonita.tds.zip
install/fonts/softmakerfreefont/broadway.tds.zip
install/fonts/softmakerfreefont/canossa.tds.zip
install/fonts/softmakerfreefont/congress.tds.zip
install/fonts/softmakerfreefont/delanocaps.tds.zip
install/fonts/softmakerfreefont/digital.tds.zip
install/fonts/softmakerfreefont/egyptiennestd.tds.zip
install/fonts/softmakerfreefont/flagstaff.tds.zip
install/fonts/softmakerfreefont/grenoble.tds.zip
install/fonts/softmakerfreefont/helium.tds.zip
install/fonts/softmakerfreefont/heliumtwo.tds.zip
install/fonts/softmakerfreefont/henderson.tds.zip
install/fonts/softmakerfreefont/iceberg.tds.zip
install/fonts/softmakerfreefont/inverserif.tds.zip
install/fonts/softmakerfreefont/jugendstil.tds.zip
install/fonts/softmakerfreefont/marseille.tds.zip
install/fonts/softmakerfreefont/moab.tds.zip
install/fonts/softmakerfreefont/nevada.tds.zip
install/fonts/softmakerfreefont/newcastle.tds.zip
install/fonts/softmakerfreefont/oldblackletter.tds.zip
install/fonts/softmakerfreefont/quadrat.tds.zip
install/fonts/softmakerfreefont/softmakerfreefont.tds.zip
install/fonts/softmakerfreefont/stonehand.tds.zip
install/fonts/softmakerfreefont/sunset.tds.zip
install/fonts/softmakerfreefont/tampa.tds.zip
install/fonts/softmakerfreefont/vagrounded.tds.zip
install/fonts/softmakerfreefont/velo.tds.zip
install/fonts/softmakerfreefont/veracruz.tds.zip
install/fonts/stix.tds.zip
install/fonts/thai/fonts-sipa-arundina.tds.zip
install/fonts/thai/fonts-tlwg.tds.zip
install/fonts/urw/antiqua.tds.zip
install/fonts/urw/arial.tds.zip
install/fonts/verdana.tds.zip
install/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikzpagenodes.tds.zip
install/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-timing.tds.zip
install/info/fifinddo-info.tds.zip
install/info/latexfileinfo-pkgs.tds.zip
install/info/luatex/lualatex-doc.tds.zip
install/info/macros2e.tds.zip
install/language/spanish/babel/base.tds.zip
install/language/thai/thailatex.tds.zip
install/language/vietnamese/vntex.tds.zip
install/macros/generic/bitelist.tds.zip
install/macros/generic/dowith.tds.zip
install/macros/generic/ifxetex.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/abstract.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/achemso.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/acronym.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/acroterm.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/addlines.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/adjustbox.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/animate.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/answers.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/appendix.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/asyfig.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/attachfile.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/auto-pst-pdf.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/bez123.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/bezos.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/authoryear-icomp-tt.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-chem.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-dw.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-ieee.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-luh-ipw.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-nature.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-science.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/historische-zeitschrift.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/bibleref-german.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/bibleref.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/bidi.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/blowup.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/booklet.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/bytefield.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/cachepic.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/caption.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/ccaption.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/changepage.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/changes.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/chappg.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/chemstyle.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/cmpj.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/collcell.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/collectbox.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/combine.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/comicsans.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/conferences/active-conf.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/conferences/icsv.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/cpssp.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/csbulletin.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/csquotes.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/csvsimple.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/csvtools.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/currfile.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/dashrule.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/datatool.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/datetime.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/dhua.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/dlfltxb.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/docmfp.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/doipubmed.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/drac.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/droit-fr.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/dvdcoll.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/easyfig.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/edfnotes.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/endfloat.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/engpron.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/engrec.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/environ.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/epigraph.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/eqparbox.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/etoolbox.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/euenc.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/everyhook.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/fancytabs.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/filecontents.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/filehook.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/fileinfo.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/filemod.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/finstrut.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/flowfram.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/fmtcount.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/fontspec.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/fonttable.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/footmisc.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/footnoterange.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/frontespizio.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/gincltex.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/gitinfo.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/gmdoc.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/gmeometric.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/gmiflink.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/gmutils.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/gmverb.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/gmverse.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/gridset.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/hanging.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/hardwrap.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/he-she.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/hrefhide.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/hyperxmp.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/hyphenat.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEconf.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/ifetex.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/ifmtarg.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/ifnextok.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/ifoddpage.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/ifplatform.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/imakeidx.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/impnattypo.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/imtekda.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/inputtrc.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/inversepath.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/jmlr.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/kantlipsum.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/l3experimental.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/l3packages.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/lastpage.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/layouts.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/lcyw.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/leading.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/lettrine.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/lineno.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/logreq.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/longnamefilelist.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/lstaddons.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/ltxdockit.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/makecmds.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/marginnote.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/mathalfa.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/mattens.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/mdframed.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/media9.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/memoir.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/mh.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/microtype.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/minibox.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/mlist.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/moderntimeline.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/modroman.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/monofill.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/morefloats.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/morehype.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/moreverb.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/mpgraphics.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/msu-thesis.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/mwe.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/needspace.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/newfile.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/newverbs.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/nicefilelist.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/nicetext.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/nonumonpart.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/notes2bib.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/nowidow.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/pagecolor.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/pagenote.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/pageslts.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/papermas.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/paresse.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/pax.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/pdf14.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/pdfcomment.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/pgfopts.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/probsoln.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/proposal.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/psnfssx/lucidabr.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/pstool.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/pst-pdf.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/pst-vowel.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/quotmark.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/rcs-multi.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/realboxes.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/realscripts.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/regstats.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/romanbar.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/romannum.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/rotating.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/rsc.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/sapthesis.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/savetrees.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/showlabels.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/splitindex.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/spverbatim.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/standalone.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/stdclsdv.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/steinmetz.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/stellenbosch.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/stex.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/storebox.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/suftesi.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/svn-multi.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/svn-prov.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/tablefootnote.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/tabvar.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/tagging.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/tdsfrmath.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/thumbs.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/titling.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/tocbibind.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/tocloft.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/tocvsec2.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/tqft.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/trimspaces.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/trivfloat.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/tufte-latex.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/undolabl.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/unicode-math.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/uri.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/usebib.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/varsfromjobname.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/verse.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/vertbars.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/vpe.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/vwcol.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/xfor.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/xltxtra.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/xpatch.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/xtab.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/yagusylo.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/contrib/ydoc.tds.zip
install/macros/latex/required/amslatex/amscls.tds.zip
install/macros/luatex/generic/lualibs.tds.zip
install/macros/luatex/generic/luamplib.tds.zip
install/macros/luatex/generic/luaotfload.tds.zip
install/macros/luatex/generic/luatexbase.tds.zip
install/macros/luatex/latex/luabibentry.tds.zip
install/macros/luatex/latex/luacode.tds.zip
install/macros/luatex/latex/luainputenc.tds.zip
install/macros/luatex/latex/lualatex-math.tds.zip
install/macros/luatex/latex/luatextra.tds.zip
install/macros/plain/plnfss.tds.zip
install/macros/xetex/latex/arabxetex.tds.zip
install/macros/xetex/latex/polyglossia.tds.zip
install/macros/xetex/latex/xepersian.tds.zip
install/macros/xetex/plain/xetexfontinfo.tds.zip
install/support/ctanupload.tds.zip
install/support/ctanWeb/install_test.tds.zip
install/support/ctanWeb/jhtest.tds.zip
install/support/pdfcrop.tds.zip
install/support/texdef.tds.zip
install/support/thumbpdf.tds.zip
install/support/typeoutfileinfo.tds.zip
language/japanese/ptex-texmf/ptex.tds.zip
macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/komascript.tds.zip
macros/latex/contrib/latex-tds/amslatex.tds.zip
macros/latex/contrib/latex-tds/babel.tds.zip
macros/latex/contrib/latex-tds/base.tds.zip
macros/latex/contrib/latex-tds/cyrillic.tds.zip
macros/latex/contrib/latex-tds/etex.tds.zip
macros/latex/contrib/latex-tds/graphics.tds.zip
macros/latex/contrib/latex-tds/knuth.tds.zip
macros/latex/contrib/latex-tds/latex-tds.tds.zip
macros/latex/contrib/latex-tds/psnfss.tds.zip
macros/latex/contrib/latex-tds/source.tds.zip
macros/latex/contrib/latex-tds/tds.tds.zip
macros/latex/contrib/latex-tds/tools.tds.zip
```

Comment: Is that really a comprehensive list? because I'm sure I had a tds of `mdframed` but that doesn't seem to be on there...

Comment: @Seamus: I can't find a TDS ZIP of `mdframed` using the CTAN file search or using Google. I will also update my answer.

Answer (score 7):

Since a few days we have added the respective link to the CTAN web site. Whenever a tds.zip file is present then a download link is provided on the package page and the tex-archive browse page.

Comment: Great news. And thanks at all for the effort!