# How to install LaTeX .zip package (from CTAN) using texhash on a 'nix system?

Tags: packages, installing

Is there an automated script which places files in the relevant directory tree in ~/texmf/ and is that all that is required to install a package (in addition to calling texhash on ~/texmf/)?

Comment: With a recent TeX Live, you don't need to `texhash` `~/texmf/`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only some packages on CTAN come also in so called TDS ZIP files which already hold the required directory structure so that you only need to unzip them over your `$TEXMF` tree (e.g. `~/texmf`). If the package author didn't uploaded a TDS ZIP file it most likely isn't on CTAN.

To my knowledge there is no direct script available which turns a CTAN package into the required TDS structure and installs it directly. (The TeXLive developers should have something like that to build the TeXLive package files.)
I was thinking writing such a script recently. So far I wrote a [Makefile which does it for most LaTeX packages](https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/ltxpkg), but currently it is `ydoc` specific, i.e. for my packages only.

However, you could download the whole CTAN directory for a package as a flat ZIP file, unpack it and then use the [`ctanify`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ctanify) script on the directory. It is intended to create an upload ZIP file for CTAN which also includes a TDS ZIP file.
You then can use this TDS ZIP file and unpack it over your TEXMF tree.

I just tested this using `colortbl` as a random example. The steps are as follows and could be turned into a script easily. Simple add `#!/bin/sh` as first line and replace `colortbl` with `$1` and call it using `yourscriptname <name of package>`. However, most but not all LaTeX package are located in `/macro/latex/contrib`, so for the others you would need to provide the download link somehow.

```
cd /tmp
wget http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/colortbl.zip
unzip colortbl.zip 
cd colortbl/
tex colortbl.ins
ctanify *.ins *.dtx
tar -xzf colortbl.tar.gz
unzip -d ~/texmf colortbl.tds.zip 
test -e ~/texmf/ls-R && texhash ~/texmf
```

Note that you only need to run `texhash` for the per-user TEXMF directory if the `ls-R` file already exists. Modern TeXLive installation search it automatically every run if the `ls-R` file doesn't exists.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: no.

Slightly longer answer: If your package is on [this list](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/install/macros/latex/contrib), kind of. The `tds.zip` files already have the structure of the TeX Directory Structure built in, so when you unzip it in the root of your `texmf` tree, all the files go in the right places. So if you download *that* zip file, then it should work.

Comment: Note that there are other directories with TDS ZIP files on CTAN, e.g. PGF related packages are not in `macros/latex/contrib` but somewhere below `graphics/..`. The package entry should link to the TDS ZIP file for the package.

Comment: Ah yes, for more on this issue, see this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24636/where-can-i-find-which-packages-are-available-as-tds-zip

Answer (score 3):

Based on @Martin Scharrer answer I made script that first tries to install from CTAN tds archive, than from texlive archive and if everything fails it will try to ctanify.

Example execution: `./script.sh makecell`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

texmf_dir=~/texmf
if wget http://mirrors.ctan.org/install/macros/latex/contrib/$1.tds.zip ; then
    unzip -d $texmf_dir $1.tds.zip
    rm $1.tds.zip
    echo installed via tds
elif wget ftp://sunsite.icm.edu.pl/pub/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet/archive/$1.tar.xz ; then
    tar -xf $1.tar.xz -C $texmf_dir
    rm $1.tar.xz
    echo installed from texlive archive  
else
    wget http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/$1.zip
    unzip $1.zip
    cd $1/
    tex $1.ins
    ctanify *.ins *.dtx
    tar -xzf $1.tar.gz
    unzip -d $texmf_dir $1.tds.zip
    cd ..
    rm -rf $1 $1.zip
    echo "installed via *.ins *.dtx"
fi
test -e ~/texmf/ls-R && texhash $texmf_dir
```