# How to install memoir package from ctan?

Tags: memoir, ctan

How do I download the memoir package from this page? http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/

I can see the directory tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/ but i'm not sure how to access it. Do I use ftp from the command line terminal? I was expecting to see a .zip file on the page. I am new to CTAN. Running OS X 10.8.4 MacTeX.

Comment: What [distribution](http://goo.gl/CqWB1) are you running? What operating system?

Comment: You should follow the instructions in [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55438/5764) to install the package(s) you're after.

Comment: As Werner says, the best way is to use your designated package manager. `LaTeX` packages are intricately related- it is often not as simple as downloading one file, as there are dependencies. In most cases, the package manager will account for these :)

Comment: Mactex already include memoir

Answer (score 1):

As a patch you can use the following script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

#me he ayudado de http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30307/how-to-install-latex-zip-package-from-ctan-using-texhash-on-a-nix-system
#listado de archivos tds disponibles: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/install/macros/latex/contrib

DIR_TEX=$(kpsewhich --expand-var '$TEXMFMAIN') #Devuelve el directorio donde TeX está instalado, en mi caso /usr/share/texmf
PAQUETE="memoir"
if [ $PAQUETE = "oberdiek" -o $PAQUETE = "environ" -o $PAQUETE = "footmisc" -o $PAQUETE = "hyperref" -o $PAQUETE = "titlesec" -o $PAQUETE = "tocloft" -o $PAQUETE = "enumitem" -o $PAQUETE = "fmtcount" -o $PAQUETE = "glossaries" -o $PAQUETE = "datatool"  -o $PAQUETE = "caption" -o $PAQUETE = "babel" -o "memoir" ] ; then #algunos paquetes están en /usr/share/texmf-texlive
    DIR_TEX=$(kpsewhich --expand-var '$TEXMFDIST')
    #DIR_TEX="$DIR_TEX-texlive"
fi 

if [ ! -f "$PAQUETE.tds.zip" ] ; then
    if [ $PAQUETE = "babel" ] ; then
        wget http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/latex-tds/$PAQUETE.tds.zip
    else
        wget http://mirrors.ctan.org/install/macros/latex/contrib/$PAQUETE.tds.zip
    fi
fi

unzip -o $PAQUETE.tds.zip -d $DIR_TEX
test -e $DIR_TEX/ls-R && texhash $DIR_TEX

#echo $DIR_TEX
```

This was done to be used with GNU/Linux, but probably with some minor fixes (like getting wget) will work in Mac.
It can be used to update and install other packages as well.

Unfortunately whether to install in TEXMFMAIN or TEXMFDIST is not automatical, although most of them, like the one you want, goes in TEXMFDIST.

That's why I would recommend you to find a proper updater with your distribution that does things automatically.

Comment: for the record, more-or-less standard UNIX tools like `wget` are there by default.