# write latex code in Lyx for tables

Tags: tables, lyx

I found this template for a table on TeX.SX:

[Beautiful table samples](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112343/beautiful-table-samples)

The table I would like to reproduce is

```
   \documentclass[12pt, oneside, landscape]{memoir}

\newif\ifblackandwhite
% \blackandwhitetrue


\usepackage{fontspec}%
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}%
\setmainfont[%
   Numbers        = OldStyle ,
   ItalicFont     = LinLibertineOI ,
   BoldItalicFont = LinLibertineOBI ,
   BoldFont       = LinLibertineOB ,
]{LinLibertineO}%


\usepackage[hmargin=2cm,vmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{longtable}%
\AtBeginEnvironment{longtable}{%
  \addfontfeature{RawFeature=+tnum;-onum}%  <--- requires LuaTeX
}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}%
  \newcommand{\myrowcolour}{\rowcolor[gray]{0.925}}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\ifblackandwhite
  \newcommand{\cheading}[2]{\textbf{#1\hfill #2}}
  \newcommand{\highest}[1]{\textbf{#1}}% == highest score for question
\else
  \newcommand{\cheading}[2]{\textcolor{Maroon}{\textbf{#1\hfill #2}}}
  \newcommand{\highest}[1]{\textcolor{Maroon}{\textbf{#1}}}%
\fi



\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\parindent0pt
%

\cheading{Fake Course Evaluation Summary for \textsc{course
    1234y}}{Sept.\ 2010 --- May 2011}

\begin{longtable}{@{}l rr rr rr rr rr rr}
% pairs: absolute number (percentage)

\toprule%
 \centering%
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{{{\bfseries Excellent}}}
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{{{\bfseries Very Good}}}
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{{{\bfseries Good}}}
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{{{\bfseries Average}}}
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{{{\bfseries Poor}}}
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{{{\bfseries Very Poor}}} \\


\cmidrule[0.4pt](r{0.125em}){1-1}%
\cmidrule[0.4pt](lr{0.125em}){2-3}%
\cmidrule[0.4pt](lr{0.125em}){4-5}%
\cmidrule[0.4pt](lr{0.125em}){6-7}%
\cmidrule[0.4pt](lr{0.125em}){8-9}%
\cmidrule[0.4pt](lr{0.125em}){10-11}%
\cmidrule[0.4pt](l{0.25em}){12-13}%
% \midrule
\endhead


Some question about the Instructor or Course & 2 & (7.14) & 4 &
(14.29) & \highest{12} & \highest{(42.86)} & 4
& (14.29) & 6 & (21.43) & 0 & (0.00) \\

\myrowcolour%
Some question about the Instructor or Course & 3 & (10.71) &
\highest{15} & \highest{(53.57)} & 5 & (17.86) & 5 & (17.86) & 0 &
(0.00) & 0 & (0.00) \\

Some question about the Instructor or Course & 4 & (14.29) & 8 &
(28.57) & \highest{15}
& \highest{(53.57)} & 1 & (3.57) & 0 & (0.00) & 0 & (0.00) \\

\myrowcolour%
Some question about the Instructor or Course & 3 & (10.71) & 8 &
(28.57) & \highest{10} & \highest{(35.71)}
& 5 & (17.86) & 2 & (7.14) & 0 & (0.00) \\

Some question about the Instructor or Course & 6 & (21.43) &
\highest{9} & \highest{(32.14)}
& 4 & (14.29) & \highest{9} & \highest{(32.14)} & 0 & (0.00) & 0 & (0.00) \\

\myrowcolour%
Some question about the Instructor or Course & \highest{10} &
\highest{(35.71)} & \highest{10} & \highest{(35.71)}
& 3 & (10.71) & 5 & (17.86) & 0 & (0.00) & 0 & (0.00) \\

Some question about the Instructor or Course & \highest{12} &
\highest{(42.86)} & \highest{12} & \highest{(42.86)} & 3
& (10.71) & 1 & (3.57) & 0 & (0.00) & 0 & (0.00) \\

\myrowcolour%
Some question about the Instructor or Course & \highest{12} &
\highest{(42.86)} & 3 & (10.71) & 7
& (25.00) & 5 & (17.86) & 1 & (3.57) & 0 & (0.00) \\

Some question about the Instructor or Course & \highest{10} &
\highest{(35.71)} & 6 & (21.43) & 6 & (21.43) & 6 & (21.43)
& 1 & (3.57) & 0 & (0.00) \\

\myrowcolour%
Some question about the Instructor or Course & 5 & (17.86) & 5 &
(17.86) & \highest{12} & \highest{(42.86)} & 2 & (7.14)
& 3 & (10.71) & 1 & (3.57)\\

Some question about the Instructor or Course & 3 & (10.71) & 8 &
(28.57) & \highest{11} & \highest{(39.29)} & 3 & (10.71) & 3 & (10.71)
& 0 & (0.00) \\

\myrowcolour%
Some question about the Instructor or Course & \highest{18} &
\highest{(64.29)}
& 5 & (17.86) & 3 & (10.71) & 1 & (3.57) & 1 & (3.57) & 0 & (0.00) \\

Some question about the Instructor or Course & \highest{15} &
\highest{(53.57)}
& 7 & (25.00) & 2 & (7.14) & 2 & (7.14) & 2 & (7.14) & 0 & (0.00) \\

\myrowcolour%
Some question about the Instructor or Course & 3 & (10.71) &
\highest{13} & \highest{(46.43)} & 4 & (14.29) & 6 & (21.43) & 2
& (7.14) & 0 & (0.00) \\

\bottomrule

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

I read that I can incorporate the first part before the begin document into the LyX file by using the Documents-->Settings-->LaTeX preamble. The I created a latex input in LyX (Ctrl + L) and entered the rest of the code (the table). However, when I try to compile everything in LyX it doesn't work. I get many error messages with `fontspec` error font not found when I hit file-->export-->Pdf(XeTEX). I think the `fontspec` package is not installed but I don't know how I can install it...can somebody tell me how I could include this table into my LyX file..?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The use of `fontspec` requires compiling with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTex, does it work if you compile with either of those?

Comment: I tried to export (PDF with XeLaTeX) in Lyx but I still get the error..for the coudnt find font error the complete message is then   ]{LinLibertineO}
                     %
|'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
| A font might not be found for many reasons.
| Check the spelling, where the font is installed etc. etc.

Comment: Forgive me, I obviously can't read, as I didn't notice that you used XeTeX already, so my previous comment was a bit pointless. You could try removing `\usepackage{fontspec}%
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}%
\setmainfont[%
   Numbers        = OldStyle ,
   ItalicFont     = LinLibertineOI ,
   BoldItalicFont = LinLibertineOBI ,
   BoldFont       = LinLibertineOB ,
]{LinLibertineO}%` and adding `\usepackage{libertine}` instead.

Comment: okay i tried this but got an error saying File libertine.sty not found

Comment: Ok. Does it work if you remove `\usepackage{libertine}`? These lines only change the font, is it important to use that specific font? As for the missing package, what TeX distribution (MikTeX, TeX Live) are you using?

Comment: if i remove the package libertine i get an error in the the first line of the ctrl plusL inserted code which is          undefined control sequence               \begin{longtable}
                      {@{}l rr rr rr rr rr rr} % pairs: absolute number (per...
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

Comment: I am using TexLive...i installed via the ubuntu software centre...

Comment: I see where that error comes from, adding `\usepackage{fontspec}` back in should fix it. I'll probably write a more comprehensive answer later. By the way, it is generally recommended to install TeX Live using the installer from TUG.org instead of Ubuntu repos, as that is usually a bit old. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092 Your code worked without modification here (TeX Live 2013 recently updated, in Kubuntu 14.04). Installing the missing font (http://www.linuxlibertine.org/index.php?id=91&L=1 I think) -- if you want to use that particular font -- is, I suppose, another option.

Comment: it would e great if you coudl wirte an answerb

Answer (score 2):

(This is sort of a summary and extension of comments.)

#### Installing

First, I'll note that the code you posted compiles without error on my system (recently updated TeX Live 2013 on Kubuntu) with either LuaTeX or XeTeX. If your system cannot find the fonts, then either they are not part of the TeX Live version that is in the Ubuntu repositories, or you haven't installed the package containing them. (I do not know which package this is.)

Usually it is recommended to install TeX Live via the installer from TUG.org ([How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu)), as the Ubuntu version of TeX Live is, or at least has been, somewhat outdated. The TUG version has the added benefit of the `tlmgr` tool, which lets you update packages as new versions appear on CTAN and in TL.

If this is not an option, and the `libertine` package, which provides these fonts, is not available in the Ubuntu repos, you can install the package manually. I haven't tried this myself, but I think you can download the `libertine.tds.zip` file from http://www.ctan.org/pkg/libertine, and unzip this in `~/texmf/`. (See e.g. http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/html/installsty.html and [How to install LaTeX .zip package (from CTAN) using texhash on a 'nix system?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30307/how-to-install-latex-zip-package-from-ctan-using-texhash-on-a-nix-system/30311#30311) -- I couldn't find better resources right now.)

Another option is to get just the OpenType font files (e.g. http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/libertine/opentype) and install these to your system, as with any other font you download. I think you can simply open them in the Font Manager (or whatever it is called) and click install.

#### Not using that font

If using that particular font is not necessary, you can try removing

```
\setmainfont[%
   Numbers        = OldStyle ,
   ItalicFont     = LinLibertineOI ,
   BoldItalicFont = LinLibertineOBI ,
   BoldFont       = LinLibertineOB ,
]{LinLibertineO}%
```

from the preamble. Then you will get the standard Latin Modern font instead. The code may then work without installing anything.

You need to keep the `fontspec` package because of the lines saying

```
\AtBeginEnvironment{longtable}{%
  \addfontfeature{RawFeature=+tnum;-onum}%  <--- requires LuaTeX
}
```

as `\addfontfeature` is defined by `fontspec`. I don't know exactly what that does though, and judging by the comment you need to compile with LuaTeX, not XeTeX, for it to have any effect.

#### Using `pdflatex` (should you for some reason want to)

If you in addition remove the `fontspec` package, the `\defaultfontfeatures` and the `\AtBeginEnvironment{longtable}{...` then you can compile with PDFLaTeX instead likely without making any changes to your system. The preamble will then look like

```
\newif\ifblackandwhite
% \blackandwhitetrue

\usepackage[hmargin=2cm,vmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}%

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\newcommand{\myrowcolour}{\rowcolor[gray]{0.925}}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\ifblackandwhite
  \newcommand{\cheading}[2]{\textbf{#1\hfill #2}}
  \newcommand{\highest}[1]{\textbf{#1}}% == highest score for question
\else
  \newcommand{\cheading}[2]{\textcolor{Maroon}{\textbf{#1\hfill #2}}}
  \newcommand{\highest}[1]{\textcolor{Maroon}{\textbf{#1}}}%
\fi
```

Finally, if you install the `libertine` package, then you can use this with PDFLaTeX as well, so to get the Libertine fonts, just add `\usepackage{libertine}` to the preamble posted just above.

#### Landscape

The table as specified is too wide for a normal page, which is why the `landscape` is added to the document class options. Such options are in LyX added via the *Custom* field in Document --> Settings --> Document Class.

However, if this table is part of a larger document, you likely don't want everything landscape, so you can use the `landscape` environment instead. Add `\begin{landscape}` at the beginning of the ERT, and `\end{landscape}` at the end. Note that you will get a page break before the landscape page.

#### Complete LyX file

The code below is a sample LyX file. You can paste it into an empty text document in a text editor (e.g. Gedit), save it as a `.lyx` file, and open it in LyX.

```
#LyX 2.0 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 413
\begin_document
\begin_header
\textclass article
\begin_preamble
\newif\ifblackandwhite
% \blackandwhitetrue

\usepackage[hmargin=2cm,vmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}%

%%% START PDFTEX-BLOCK
% To be able to use PDFTeX, remove everything within this block
\usepackage{fontspec}%
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}%
\setmainfont[%
   Numbers        = OldStyle ,
   ItalicFont     = LinLibertineOI ,
   BoldItalicFont = LinLibertineOBI ,
   BoldFont       = LinLibertineOB ,
]{LinLibertineO}%
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{longtable}{%
  \addfontfeature{RawFeature=+tnum;-onum}%  <--- requires LuaTeX
}
%%% END BLOCK


\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}%
  \newcommand{\myrowcolour}{\rowcolor[gray]{0.925}}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\ifblackandwhite
  \newcommand{\cheading}[2]{\textbf{#1\hfill #2}}
  \newcommand{\highest}[1]{\textbf{#1}}% == highest score for question
\else
  \newcommand{\cheading}[2]{\textcolor{Maroon}{\textbf{#1\hfill #2}}}
  \newcommand{\highest}[1]{\textcolor{Maroon}{\textbf{#1}}}%
\fi
\end_preamble
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman default
\font_sans default
\font_typewriter default
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100
\font_tt_scale 100

\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_amsmath 1
\use_esint 1
\use_mhchem 1
\use_mathdots 1
\cite_engine basic
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\use_refstyle 1
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\quotes_language english
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Standard
Some text on a page.
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
begin{landscape}
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
thispagestyle{empty}%
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
parindent0pt%
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
cheading{Fake Course Evaluation Summary for 
\backslash
textsc{course     1234y}}{Sept.
\backslash
 2010 --- May 2011}%
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
begin{longtable}{@{}l rr rr rr rr rr rr}
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
toprule
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
centering
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

  & 
\backslash
multicolumn{2}{c}{{{
\backslash
bfseries Excellent}}}
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

  & 
\backslash
multicolumn{2}{c}{{{
\backslash
bfseries Very Good}}}
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

  & 
\backslash
multicolumn{2}{c}{{{
\backslash
bfseries Good}}}
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

  & 
\backslash
multicolumn{2}{c}{{{
\backslash
bfseries Average}}}
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

  & 
\backslash
multicolumn{2}{c}{{{
\backslash
bfseries Poor}}}
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

  & 
\backslash
multicolumn{2}{c}{{{
\backslash
bfseries Very Poor}}} 
\backslash

\backslash

\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
cmidrule[0.4pt](r{0.125em}){1-1}
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
cmidrule[0.4pt](lr{0.125em}){2-3}
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
cmidrule[0.4pt](lr{0.125em}){4-5}
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
cmidrule[0.4pt](lr{0.125em}){6-7}
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
cmidrule[0.4pt](lr{0.125em}){8-9}
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
cmidrule[0.4pt](lr{0.125em}){10-11}
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
cmidrule[0.4pt](l{0.25em}){12-13}
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
endhead
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

Some question about the Instructor or Course & 2 & (7.14) & 4 & (14.29) &

\backslash
highest{12} & 
\backslash
highest{(42.86)} & 4 & (14.29) & 6 & (21.43) & 0 & (0.00) 
\backslash

\backslash

\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
myrowcolour Some question about the Instructor or Course & 3 & (10.71) &

\backslash
highest{15} & 
\backslash
highest{(53.57)} & 5 & (17.86) & 5 & (17.86) & 0 & (0.00) & 0 & (0.00) 
\backslash

\backslash

\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

Some question about the Instructor or Course & 4 & (14.29) & 8 & (28.57) &

\backslash
highest{15} & 
\backslash
highest{(53.57)} & 1 & (3.57) & 0 & (0.00) & 0 & (0.00) 
\backslash

\backslash

\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
myrowcolour Some question about the Instructor or Course & 3 & (10.71) &
 8 & (28.57) & 
\backslash
highest{10} & 
\backslash
highest{(35.71)} & 5 & (17.86) & 2 & (7.14) & 0 & (0.00) 
\backslash

\backslash

\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

Some question about the Instructor or Course & 6 & (21.43) & 
\backslash
highest{9} & 
\backslash
highest{(32.14)} & 4 & (14.29) & 
\backslash
highest{9} & 
\backslash
highest{(32.14)} & 0 & (0.00) & 0 & (0.00) 
\backslash

\backslash

\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
myrowcolour Some question about the Instructor or Course & 
\backslash
highest{10} & 
\backslash
highest{(35.71)} & 
\backslash
highest{10} & 
\backslash
highest{(35.71)} & 3 & (10.71) & 5 & (17.86) & 0 & (0.00) & 0 & (0.00) 
\backslash

\backslash

\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

Some question about the Instructor or Course & 
\backslash
highest{12} & 
\backslash
highest{(42.86)} & 
\backslash
highest{12} & 
\backslash
highest{(42.86)} & 3 & (10.71) & 1 & (3.57) & 0 & (0.00) & 0 & (0.00) 
\backslash

\backslash

\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
myrowcolour Some question about the Instructor or Course & 
\backslash
highest{12} & 
\backslash
highest{(42.86)} & 3 & (10.71) & 7 & (25.00) & 5 & (17.86) & 1 & (3.57) & 0 &
 (0.00) 
\backslash

\backslash

\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

Some question about the Instructor or Course & 
\backslash
highest{10} & 
\backslash
highest{(35.71)} & 6 & (21.43) & 6 & (21.43) & 6 & (21.43) & 1 & (3.57) & 0 &
 (0.00) 
\backslash

\backslash

\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
myrowcolour Some question about the Instructor or Course & 5 & (17.86) &
 5 & (17.86) & 
\backslash
highest{12} & 
\backslash
highest{(42.86)} & 2 & (7.14) & 3 & (10.71) & 1 & (3.57)
\backslash

\backslash

\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

Some question about the Instructor or Course & 3 & (10.71) & 8 & (28.57) &

\backslash
highest{11} & 
\backslash
highest{(39.29)} & 3 & (10.71) & 3 & (10.71) & 0 & (0.00) 
\backslash

\backslash

\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
myrowcolour Some question about the Instructor or Course & 
\backslash
highest{18} & 
\backslash
highest{(64.29)} & 5 & (17.86) & 3 & (10.71) & 1 & (3.57) & 1 & (3.57) & 0 &
 (0.00) 
\backslash

\backslash

\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

Some question about the Instructor or Course & 
\backslash
highest{15} & 
\backslash
highest{(53.57)} & 7 & (25.00) & 2 & (7.14) & 2 & (7.14) & 2 & (7.14) & 0 & (0.00)

\backslash

\backslash

\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
myrowcolour Some question about the Instructor or Course & 3 & (10.71) &

\backslash
highest{13} & 
\backslash
highest{(46.43)} & 4 & (14.29) & 6 & (21.43) & 2 & (7.14) & 0 & (0.00) 
\backslash

\backslash

\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
bottomrule
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
end{longtable}
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
end{landscape}
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
Sone more text on the next page.
\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```