# Generate .sty file from CTAN zip

Tags: packages

I want to install a new package to my Tex environment, as an example [Colortbl from CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/colortbl).

The issue is I am behind a firewall at my company so I cannot download it through my tex environment.

Going to CTAN I get a zip file with:

- colortbl.dtx
- colortbl.ins
- colortbl.pdf
- colortbl-DE.pdf
- colortbl-DE.tex
- README

How do I get the needed .sty file?

Comment: Depending on the platform, I think this is a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30307/how-to-install-latex-zip-package-from-ctan-using-texhash-on-a-nix-system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After it is downloaded unpack it to where you want either in the tex root folder:

```
.../tex/latex/colortbl/
```

Where you create the folder colortbl, or unpack it within the folder with your .tex files for the specific project where you want to use colortbl.

For Windows open `cmd`, in the folder where the unpacked files are and type:

```
pdflatex colortbl.ins
```

it will then generate the .sty file that you need.

Comment: For small packages that is okay, but for large packages where the files must then moved to various folders it can get tiring. I would download the package files from the tex environment and create a local repository.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I completely agree, I just had terrible issues with the firewall and adiministrator rights on the PC. This was the only solution I could come up with unfortunately