# I need forest.sty package

Tags: packages, forest, ctan

My Tex code works super good in overleaf and TexMaker, but once it is uploaded to a journal platform (submission procedure), it requires all the packages used.

I didn't find the `forest.sty` package. I searched over [CTAN repository](https://ctan.org), I found many packages for `forest` by their names don't match the needed file (i.e, `forest.sty`).

Where can I find this package ?

Thanks

Comment: https://ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/forest

Comment: You're probably referring to [the `forest` package](//ctan.org/pkg/forest). It's source is located [here](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/forest). You'll have to compile `forest.ins` in order to generate `forest.sty` ([details](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/293983/5764) - possible duplicate); for this you'll need a local installation.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're apparently able to run the file locally (based on the mention of TeXmaker), that means you likely have it on your system. In TeXmaker, there's a button at the bottom of the screen **Messages/Log**. Click on that and you'll see a transcript of your LaTeX run. You can scroll through that and near the top, you'll see where the file is loaded from.

That's the easy part. The hard part, is whether the journal requires *all* the external packages. Because `forest` is a Ti*k*Z extension and will load a few dozen Ti*k*Z and pgf files as well. I'm guessing that the journal is being overly cautious in their requirements and you could probably leave out any of the CTAN packages from your submission and obey the letter of the law for their process by sending `forest.sty` alone, but ultimately the journal production staff would have to be the ones to make that call.