# how to Install new packages during freeze period

Tags: texlive, texlive-2017, tlmgr

Apparently TeX Live 2017 is now in the freeze period in anticipation of Tex Live 2018, because I tried running `sudo tlmgr install tikz` (for a re-install of TeX Live I was doing), and I hit this error:

```
TeX Live 2017 is frozen forever and will no
longer be updated.  This happens in preparation for a new release.

If you're interested in helping to pretest the new release (when
pretests are available), please read http://tug.org/texlive/pretest.html.
Otherwise, just wait, and the new release will be ready in due time.
tlmgr: package repository http://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/systems/texlive/tlnet (verified)
tlmgr: saving backups to /usr/local/texlive/2017/tlpkg/backups
tlmgr: no updates available
```

Given I don't have the time to wait until whenever TeX Live 2018 releases to install `tikz`, is there a way to circumvent the freeze, or will I have to manually install packages from CTAN?

Comment: You could use the pretests: http://www.tug.org/texlive/pretest.html -- the updates on CTAN will enter the pretests as well. I have never used it so far, however

Comment: AFAIK tikz haven't been updated for tl18, and you should not have any problems installing tl17 from the frozen repositories

Comment: In general packages which provide TDS ZIP files can be installed into your own TEXMF directory simply by unzipping. I don't know if TikZ/PGF is provided as TDS ZIP file in particular.

Comment: Good news! There is a [PGF TDS ZIP file](http://mirrors.ctan.org/install/graphics/pgf/base/pgf.tds.zip) on CTAN! See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30311/2975 on how to install it (on a Unix-like System).

Comment: Doesn't this means that tikz is alresdy installed on your system?

Comment: @daleif: Indeed, looking at the CTAN page: v3.0.1a 2015-08-29. So PGF/TikZ should be installable or updateable with TL'17. Brain: The freeze only means that no updates to the TL packages are made from updates of the CTAN packages. You still can install and update packages to the latest versions available on TL.

Comment: how did you install texlive 2017 and not get tikz?

Comment: You showed the output of `tlmgr update --all`; if you issue `tlmgr install <package>` you will get the warning of TeX LIve being frozen, but `<package>` will be installed, if not yet present on your distribution.

Comment: Oh, I installed a minimal version of TeX Live (I had less than 10GB of space on my hard drive), so I think tikz didn't ship.

Answer (score 2):

1. You claim to have issued `sudo tlmgr install tikz`, but if I do it on my machine I get

   ```
   > sudo tlmgr install tikz
   TeX Live 2017 is frozen forever and will no
   longer be updated.  This happens in preparation for a new release.

   If you're interested in helping to pretest the new release (when
   pretests are available), please read http://tug.org/texlive/pretest.html.
   Otherwise, just wait, and the new release will be ready in due time.
   tlmgr: package repository http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet (verified)
   tlmgr install: package tikz not present in repository.
   tlmgr: action install returned an error; continuing.
   tlmgr: An error has occurred. See above messages. Exiting.
   ```
2. If I try to install an already installed package, I get

   ```
   > sudo tlmgr install regexpatch
   TeX Live 2017 is frozen forever and will no
   longer be updated.  This happens in preparation for a new release.

   If you're interested in helping to pretest the new release (when
   pretests are available), please read http://tug.org/texlive/pretest.html.
   Otherwise, just wait, and the new release will be ready in due time.
   tlmgr: package repository http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet (verified)
   tlmgr install: package already present: regexpatch
   ```
3. I only get the message you report if I try to *update*:

   ```
   > sudo tlmgr update --all
   TeX Live 2017 is frozen forever and will no
   longer be updated.  This happens in preparation for a new release.

   If you're interested in helping to pretest the new release (when
   pretests are available), please read http://tug.org/texlive/pretest.html.
   Otherwise, just wait, and the new release will be ready in due time.
   tlmgr: package repository http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet (verified)
   tlmgr: saving backups to /usr/local/texlive/2017/tlpkg/backups
   tlmgr: no updates available
   ```

Now, if you don't have TikZ/PGF on your machine, the correct way to install it should be

```
sudo tlmgr install pgf
```

Comment: Huh, that is really weird. I guess I really do have tikz after all. Funny thing is, I tried compiling a TeX document with tikz, and the compiler said tikz wasn't found.

Comment: The last line of the answer `sudo tlmgr install pgf` DOES NOT work for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, Bionic.

Comment: @oaxacamatt It depends on how you installed TeX Live. If you installed the Debian version, `tlmgr` only works for a single user and you can’t use it for installing packages system-wide.

Comment: @egreg I believe I installed Tinytex through RStudio.